Rest Assured verifying JSON list of key/value pairs
Using Rest Assured (io.restassured) in Java and have the following JSON response format
{
"products": [
    {
      "name": "toy1",
      "price": 99
    },
    {
      "name": "toy2",
      "price": 88
    },
    {
      "name": "toy3",
      "price": 99
    }
  ]
}

I'm trying to find if a specific product exist given it's name and price.
So the following result (or assert) is expected



name
price
isExist




toy1
99
true


toy2
99
false


toy2
88
true


sometoy
99
false



I tried:

converting the JSON into a list of maps, but the overall solution was really messy
found a package that would be convenient and solve my problem, but there's restrictions preventing me from using it
considered flattening it, but that won't work since there would be key clashes


There are 2 solutions

Create a POJO class for the sample JSON (leverage online json to pojo converters - https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo)
If you don't want to create extra POJO class, you can go ahead with io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.

Here's an example of 2nd one.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Example JSON response
    String jsonResponse = "{ \"products\": ["
            + "{ \"name\": \"toy1\", \"price\": 99 },"
            + "{ \"name\": \"toy2\", \"price\": 88 },"
            + "{ \"name\": \"toy3\", \"price\": 99 }"
            + "] }";

    // Parse JSON response
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonResponse);

    // Check for product existence
    System.out.println(doesProductExist("toy1", 99, jsonPath)); // true
    System.out.println(doesProductExist("toy2", 99, jsonPath)); // false
    System.out.println(doesProductExist("toy2", 88, jsonPath)); // true
    System.out.println(doesProductExist("sometoy", 99, jsonPath)); // false
}

public static boolean doesProductExist(String name, int price, JsonPath jsonPath) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> products = jsonPath.getList("products");
    return products.stream()
        .anyMatch(product -> name.equals(product.get("name")) && price == (int) product.get("price"));
}


This solution worked for me of not creating a POJO. Instead of using stream operators, I decided to just use a for loop. I did get some data type issues, but resolved that. Thank you!
Looking at it right now, it seems so obvious, but hindsight is always 20/20.
